# Inserting multiple rows in single indexed table Vs inserting single row in a table with multiple indexes

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck in a situation,

where either I can opt to make the process such that it will enter a single row to table with 20 indexes.

Or I can create one more table and enter 20 rows inside it (along with entering the single row in the first table). In this situation, both tables will have single index each.

My first table (in both the scenarios) will receive lots of read/Write. Whereas second table (in the second scenario) will get lots of write and few reads.

Which of the two would be the better choice?

In case this description sounds too abstract, I will update the question with actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a table from a flat file that has repeating sets in it, and you are trying to decide whether it would be best to have a process to normalize the data as well as keeping a copy of the raw data, or just index all over the raw data in its original form.

I would say you should have the normalized table, as this will simplify queries that would otherwise be using `union all` over each column set from the big flat table. This will also let you eliminate column sets that are `null` or duplicates.